# Plot a table in R with multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe and I want to Plot a table that simply shows the output in a Table using R's graphics:

so it looks like this, but in the graphics window:

```
Letter   Color   Age  Height
  A        10      7     11 
  B        8       6     10
  C        9       5     4
```

I thought I could use:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=colnames(df))+geom_bar('identity'))
```

But what do I fill as the y-coordinates/values on the table?

Comment: try `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(key, val, -Letter) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Letter, y = val, fill = key)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reshape into 'long' format with `gather` and then do the bar plot with `geom_bar`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  gather(key, val, -Letter) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Letter, y = val, fill = key)) + 
             geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
barplot(`colnames<-`(t(df[-1]), df$Letter), legend = TRUE,
              col = c('red', 'blue', 'green'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Letter = c("A", "B", "C"), Color = c(10L, 8L, 
9L), Age = c(7L, 6L, 5L), Height = c(11L, 10L, 4L)), .Names = c("Letter", 
"Color", "Age", "Height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Thanks, regarding your other question, I think you had copied the data without removing the fancy lines

Comment: Sure Arun checking on it, thank you for guiding as always.